# Calling multiple nested object recursively giving undefined

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple algo whose job is to find the corresponding name where the profession is teacher.

The given code calls the function recursively until the given result is achieved.

On executing the code, I am getting the final output is `undefined`. where as I was expecting the name to be ishan.

Can someone help me in diagnosing the problem in my algo?

```js
   
    //Accessing infitely nested Array
    // Infinitely nested Array

    const infiniteArray = [
      {
        name: "Jack",
        age: "98",
        profession: "doctor",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Varun",
            age: "80",
            profession: "scientist",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Ishan",
                age: "62",
                profession: "teacher"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    
    
    
    const accessNestedObject = (infiniteArray) => {
      return infiniteArray.forEach(element => {
        if (element['profession'] === 'teacher') {
          console.log(element.name)
          return element.name
        } else {
          console.log(element["children"])
          return accessNestedObject(element["children"])
        }
      });
    }
    
    const result = accessNestedObject(infiniteArray)
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: `return`ing from `forEach` callback doesn't do what you think. Use `for` or `for..of` loop instead. Another option is [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @anny123, your array model could be changed, instead specfiy individual entity having reference to its parent based on primary key value, then your code will succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` because that's the expected return value of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

You have to declare a variable that will store the final result of your loop.

```js
//Accessing infitely nested Array
// Infinitely nested Array

const infiniteArray = [
  {
    name: "Jack",
    age: "98",
    profession: "doctor",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Varun",
        age: "80",
        profession: "scientist",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Ishan",
            age: "62",
            profession: "teacher"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];



const accessNestedObject = (infiniteArray) => {
  let result = null;

  infiniteArray.forEach(element => {
    if (element.profession === 'teacher') {
      result = element.name;
    } else {
      result = accessNestedObject(element.children);
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}

const result = accessNestedObject(infiniteArray);
console.log(result);
```